# Disable 2nd select list values that are less than the selected value of prior list

Tags: selectlist

I have 2 selectLists, Start Time and End Time.

When Start Time is selected End Time list is rerendered to a time later than start time but I would also like to disable all End Time values that are < than Start Time values.

If anyone has an example or can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a specific set of times to be selected from, you can use a map where key is start time and value is list of appropriate values of end time for that start time, and when particular start time is selected take its corresponding list of end time and render that to the END TIME.

If Start time and End Time are custom fields then you can simply make start time as controlling and end time as dependent pick list.Where you can select for a specific value of start time which values should end time be rendering.